# How to disable automatic appending X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest into uri?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery, ajaxform

I use Ajax.BeginForm.. It loads me partial view. This view have links. After view is  loaded via ajax each link has href that ends with X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest.
How can I disable automatic appending this parameter to my links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This header is sent by jQuery everytime you perform an AJAX request. You could try disabling it by globally subscribing to the [`ajaxSend`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) handler and overriding its value:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', { 
        toString: function() { return ''; } 
    });
});
```

Notice that this will only set the value of the header to an empty string. It won't remove it from the request. A [`bug has been filed`](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13491) in jQuery asking to have the possibility to completely remove this request header and apparently it was rejected as not a bug.